# Mac file sharing (smbd) wedged, how to debug?

Tags: network, wifi, time-machine, file-sharing

I have a 2020 M1 Mac Mini running Ventura 13.2.1 as a file server, and an old 2015 Macbook Pro running Monterey 12.6.3 trying to connect to the shared drive. The connection gets wedged in some kind of halfway state that I cannot figure out how to reset.

On the laptop, the mini appears as a network location in the sidebar. When I click on it, I get a finder window with the machine name, "Connected as: ", and a [Disconnect] button -- but *nothing else*. None of the shared folders or drives appears in the Finder window. When I click "Disconnect", nothing happens. I cannot transfer any files, because the directory does not populate.

When I try to back up to Time Machine, it gets stuck at "Looking for backup drive…", then eventually fails with "Backup Disk Not Available", "Try backing up again when <machine>.local is available."

I have tried rebooting both computers. This did not fix anything.

I have turned File Sharing off and then on again on the server mini. This did not fix anything.

The laptop is connected to my network via wifi, and the mini is connected to the same router via ethernet cable.

I am comfortable with unix command line and have looked for documentation of smbd/launchctl on the mac, but have not found anything that looks helpful and remotely up-to-date.

I've tried looking for errors in Console, but there's nothing from smbd and I can't pick out anything else I recognize from the stream. I don't know what I should be looking for.

This used to work, then just silently stopped.

Help?

Comment: For what it's worth, I *can* connect from the mini to the laptop (the not-useful direction), but *not* from the laptop to the mini.

Comment: `ping <machine>.local` succeeds, packets transmitted and received

Comment: What do you get if you run `smbutil view smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` on the laptop (replacing the `xxx`s with the numeric IPv4 address of the server – NOT its mDNS `.local` name)?

Comment: `% smbutil view smb://192.168.1.106`
`smbutil: server connection failed: Operation timed out`

Comment: Let's check what server ports are visible to the laptop. Run `sudo nmap 192.168.1.106` from the laptop (you can get `nmap` from https://nmap.org or via the usual package managers, e.g., `brew install nmap`).

Comment: @pion, port 445 is open, identified as 'microsoft-ds'. Which seems ok?